# css and master page asp.net problem

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

i had used the following code in master page of asp.net project

```
<a runat="server" href="home.htm" onmouseover="document.Home_Img.src='Images/home_2.png'"
        onmouseout="document.Home_Img.src='Images/home.png'">
        <img alt="" src="Images/home.png" name="Home_Img" runat="server" />
    </a>
```

It is working well for all associated webforms in the root directory but not in the sub directory pages.
any sugesstion would be respected.

Thnx in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the URL's of your wrapped in the ResolveUrl like so:

```
<a runat="server" href="<%= this.ResolveUrl("home.htm") %>" onmouseover="document.Home_Img.src='<%= this.ResolveUrl("Images/home_2.png") %>'"
        onmouseout="document.Home_Img.src='<%= this.ResolveUrl("Images/home.png") %>'">
        <img alt="" src="Images/home.png" name="Home_Img" runat="server" />
    </a>
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using a relative URL `Images/home.png` for the image location, change it to absolute `/Images/home.png`:

```
<a runat="server" href="home.htm" onmouseover="document.Home_Img.src='/Images/home_2.png'"
        onmouseout="document.Home_Img.src='/Images/home.png'">
        <img alt="" src="/Images/home.png" name="Home_Img" runat="server" />
    </a>
```

Also, this has nothing to do with CSS since you're using old school Javascript mouseovers. I would strongly suggest you change it to something like:

```
<style>
a.home {
    background: url(/Images/home.png) no-repeat;
    display: block; /* this may not be correct, depends on the layout */
    height: 100px; /* height of image */
    text-indent: 9999px;
    width: 100px; /* width of image */
}
a.home:hover {
    background: url(/Images/home_2.png) no-repeat;
}
</style>

<a class="home" href="home.htm">Home</a>
```